# Manifest merger failed. What to do?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Trying to run application on emulator but theres a bug and it says:

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91  is also present at
>   [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>   value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).   Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element
>   at AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-24:19 to override.

Ive looked many of this same question and didn't find answer to my problem.

My AndroidManifest.xml

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.cubehelppp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="allowBackup, label">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I got these bugs from Merged Manifest:

```
Merging Errors: 
Error: Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory). Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-24:19 to override. app main manifest (this file), line 21
```

What to do? (Post updated to a new problem)

Comment: Are you using firebase or google play services?

Comment: Im not sure (Don't know where to see) I think i use google play services.

Comment: did you tried `add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"`

Comment: Migrate your project to AndroidX or user google play services version below 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try migrating your project to AndroidX.
To migrate, **Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX**

Answer (score 0):

1. You can just remove it :-

   ```
   tools:replace="android:supportsRtl,android:appComponentFactory".
   ```
2. added this are :-

   ```
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   tools:replace="allowBackup, label"
   ```

Comment: Did this and updated post there's still a bug. Do you know what to do?

Comment: this needs clarification